# Conflict when installing PHP intl extension for composer on Centos 7

Tags: php, linux, centos, composer-php, magento2

I am trying to do a Magento 2 DRC installation on a remote linux server, running Centos 7, Apache 2.4.6, MariaDB and PHP v5.6.9. When I try to install Composer I get the following message:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/magento2 && composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system.
```

I have installed `ext-intl` using:

```
yum list php*intl
```

and

```
yum install php-intl
```

But is still gives me the same message.

I have tried various other installations to get around the problem, to no avail. Any suggestions would be gratefully erceived as it is stalling the project.

Would it help to downgrade to PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps for magento2 installation on Centos 7.
http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-centos-7/

There are few easy steps to install Magento 2(M2) on Centos Distro.

Step 1-:
First of all we need to add few EPEL repositories for the php5.6, mysql-server5.6, and phpmyadmin.

```
     # EPEL Repository for php5.6
        $ rpm -iUvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
        $ rpm -iUvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
        # EPEL Repository for mysql-server5.6
        $rpm -iUvh http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
        # EPEL Repository for phpMyadmin on Centos 7
        $ rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
        $ yum -y update
```

Step 2-:

Install Require packages like apache, php5.6, mysql-server, phpmyadmin.

```
      $ yum install-y httpd php mysql-server phpmyadmin php56w-mcrypt php56w-intl php56w-xsl git
```

To allow the phpmyadmin in apache 2.4 add the line

Require all granted

Readmore go to above link

Comment: the "56w" characters after php did the trick for me, your a life saver

Answer (score 1):

**Magento2 installation on RHEL/Centos 7 with Php7.**

Subscribing to the IUS Community Project Repository
Since PHP 7.x is not yet packaged in official repositories for the major distributions, we’ll have to rely on a third-party source. Several repositories offer PHP 7 RPM files. We’ll use the IUS repository.

**IUS offers an installation script for subscribing to their repository and importing associated GPG keys. Make sure you’re in your home directory, and retrieve the script using curl:**

```
curl 'https://setup.ius.io/' -o setup-ius.sh
sudo bash setup-ius.sh
```

Install Required Packages-:

```
sudo yum install -y mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd php70u-json php70u-gd php70u-dom php70u-simplexml php70u-mcrypt php70u-intl httpd mysql-server git
```

See my Article for Complete Installation [magento2-php7-centos7-mysql5.7](http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-php7-centos7rhel/)

Answer (score 0):

The extension has to be installed and activated for the command line PHP, not only for the web server PHP. If you run `php -i`, which is the CLI equivalent of running `phpinfo()`, you should see a section containing info about the "intl" extension. If this is missing, you'd also see the path to the "php.ini" file that is being used - this is where you should double check whether or not the extension is activated or not.

Most of the time, it is not.

Comment: Hi Sven,thanks for your response. I ran php -i from the command line and you are quite correct, I could not see an entry for "intl". So I ran yum install php intl and got the following error message

Comment: Just reinstalled intl and run php -i | grep intl. It gives me an answer, which suggests it is installed and running, but does not show when I run php -m or php -i.

Comment: I added the line extension=intl.so in the php.ini file which has not worked, so I created the file /etc/php5/conf.d/intl.ini and put the line extension=intl.so into it, restarted apache and it is still not showing. I am totally confused.

Comment: First of all, you don't have to restart Apache when updating configuration for command line PHP - PHP isn't running in the background for the command line. Second, `php -i` should list the php.ini file it is using. Edit that one, don't invent new ones. It's likely that there may be an existing configuration directory containing multiple ini files for one extension each, and you'd simply add one for the intl extension there. This directory is also listed in `php -i`.

Comment: I have edited the php.ini file at /etc/php.ini using vi. Does it matter where I insert the line? I still cannot activate "intl". I believe there may be a version issue. Would it help to go back one release on php?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm a little late here but...

restart your php or httpd service and after restart the php-fpm service and that's it.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.